# How to turn off Typescript Language Basics suggestions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I find Typescript Language Basics suggestions annoying - they always come on top of my suggestion and I would like to turn them off. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't disable it but with this setting you can make appear below useful suggestions:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"
```

[image]

---

before changing settings suggestions: [image]

after changing settings suggestions: [image]

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a way to move them to bottom with `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"`. I don't know why isn't this default.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the file. On my Mac, the snippets file was located at `/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-basics/snippets/typescript.code-snippets`. Deleting that file did it for me.

All VS Code snippet files have the `.code-snippets` extension, so you can just do a file search for that extension and get rid of any ones you don't like!

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2019, adding this to `settings.json` disabled it for me:

```
  "editor.suggest.showSnippets": false,
```

Comment: yeah but this also hides user snippets

Comment: Indeed. But to your answer - I've always had the snippets at the bottom. However, when bringing up the context menu the first selected item is always right in the middle of the context menu. Which means that I need to scroll to the top to find the relevent items. Hence why hiding all snippets solved it for me.

Comment: you're right. FWIW I changed my machine and on the fresh VSCode setup the suggestion seem to work better- perhaps they have updated it somehow

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off snippet suggestions by setting `"editor.suggest.filteredTypes": { "snippet": false }`

Answer (score 0):

```
 "typescript.format.enable" : false,
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_formatting

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.